# Validate New Admin User's Password

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, password, change-password

I've been building an enhanced password policy module for Magento 1.9, the specifics of which aren't causing a problem.

At the moment it hooks into `admin_user_validate`, fired from `Mage_Admin_Model_User:563` event and validates the `$observer->getUser()->getData('new_password')`, which works fine when validating password changes for existing users, however I can't seem to get it to work for validating a new user's password.

I can see from `Mage_Admin_Model_User` that the event is only fired within the `if ($this->hasNewPassword())` conditional, which wouldn't be triggered by a new user, so I guess my question is, does anyone know if there is another event that is triggered by both new and existing users, or is there a better way to validate password changes, preferably via an observer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following event

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
            <observers>
                <custom_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
                    <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                    <method>validatePasswordAdminAccountSaveAction</method>
                </custom_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

And method is

```
/**
 * Validate password before admin account save action
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function validatePasswordAdminAccountSaveAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    $password = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getPost('new_password');

    if (!empty($password)) {
        if(!$this->validateAdminPassword($password)) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/system_account/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, the generic pre-dispatch event, how could I forget :) I'm going to mark this as correct as the logic works, but for anyone reading this in the future, the event I hooked into was `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_save`. Cheers Sohel.